# When implementing session clustering by storing refreshToken in Redis, would it be better to set the key to refreshToken? Or use userId?

Tags: redis, jwt, microservices

I summarized what I know. If there are any mistakes or improvements, please let me know :)

### Save RefreshToken with refreshToken key? or userId key?

- Key : RefreshToken

  - Pros

    - Easily find refreshToken valid
    - Can be performed as Clustered Session.
  - Cons

    - In case of Clustered Session, deplicated user can be logged in. If you want to use this refreshToken like Session, you have to find all keys that contains userId which is very time consuming!
- Key : userId

  - Pros

    - Easily manage based on userId
    - Can be performed as Clustered Session. And duplicated users are not accessed. So when you login and also already login data exist in redis, you can cut off that login data and refresh it!
  - Cons

    - Additional process which need to find userId. I think this is quite difficult. Since our servers are spread, if you choose this method, you need to configure all server's JwtTokenValidation to find out userId which is hide inside Token.
    - Unless using RefreshToken as key.

### To sum up

- If you want to manage your service permitting duplicated user login

you can use key with refreshToken

- If you want to manage your service permitting only one user login

you can use key with userId

### In my case

I don't want to manage duplicated session. And I need simple process that just see redis clustered session storage, check userId based on refreshToken. So I use RefreshToken as key!

Please tell me if there is anything wrong with my knowledge or if there is anything for improvement.